# how to disabled post button when textarea contain only blank white spacing or empty in reactJs

Tags: reactjs

//disabled post button when textarea contain only  blank white spacing or empty in reactJs

import { useState } from "react";

```
const CommentForm = ({ handleSubmit, submitLabel }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const textType = "plainText"
  const textDisabled = text.length === 0
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleSubmit(text,null,textType);
    setText("")
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <textarea
        className="comment-form-textarea"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button className="comment-form-button" disabled={textDisabled} >{submitLabel}</button>
    </form>

  );
};

export default CommentForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const textDisabled = text.length === 0 || text.trim().length === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the given condition it checks the string has any charector, you can use just **text** (empty string is false value) or to exclude space **text.trim()**.

Button disabled can be written as (not-text.trim() which gives true when there is no charectors nor an empty space)

```html
<button className="comment-form-button" disabled={!text.trim()} >{submitLabel}</button>
```